# How do I edit the shortcuts in the Nautilus Elementary side bar?

Tags: nautilus, mount, nautilus-elementary

Today I install Ubuntu 10.04 and Nautilus-elementary. I mounted 5 folders in home folder from my home server with NFS. Please look at the picture:

[image]

I have 3 questions:

1) How can I remove not all, but some mounted folders from left part of Nautilus-elementary? I marked it on picture.

2) How can I remove hard drive icons from mounted folders? I marked this icons on picture too.

3) How can I set it so that mounted folders don't appear on the desktop?

Sorry for my English :)

Answer (score 1):

1) and 2): I think it's not possible.

3) open `gconf-editor`, select `/apps/nautilus/desktop` and deselect `volumes_visible` from right pane.

Answer (score 0):

Properties → Image → searching for the icon of the original folder that I believe is in /usr/share/icons/Humanity/places/64/folder.svg but there are other sizes on /usr/share/icons/Humanity/places/